# Search Placemarks Google Earth API

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I know in the Google Earth client you can search for a placemark is there a way to implement this type of feature for the API. We have different placemarks that users would like to search then fly to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of ways to search for placemarks, really it would depend on how you have defined or created them.

For example, are they defined in a KML file, or created via the API? Also, do they have any [abstract view](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_abstract_view) defined, or are they simply based on point geometry?

One of the easiest ways would be to use the [various accessors](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/accessors) to find the placemarks. For example if the placemark has an ID you can use `getElementById()` and presuming the placemarks have an abstract view you can use that to look at, or fly to, it.

```
var placemark = ge.getElementById('MyPlacemark');
if (placemark.getAbstractView()) {
   ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
}
```

Or else if you are loading KML by its URL, e.g.

```
// loaded via KML
var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl('http://yoursite.com/foo.kml#MyPlacemark');
if (placemark.getAbstractView()) {
   ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
}
```

If the placemark doesn't have an abstract view you can still use the accessors to find the correct placemark and then extract the geometry from it to create the look at.

```
var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl('http://yoursite.com/foo.kml#MyPlacemark');
var point = placemark.getGeometry();
var lat = point.getLatitude();
var lng = point.getLongitude();
```

Without more information on how you have defined your placemarks it is pretty hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

what about KmlObjectList GEPlugin.getElementsByType?

Comment: The placemarks are generated on a server. The KML is just a network link back to them. The placemarks can be thought of as a commerical air traffic view. It is constantly changing and updating. They are plotted via Lat/Lon.